# Search API, find RSS Feeds?

Tags: soap, service, search-engine

Im looking for a search api that will allow me to search for rss feeds.

It will either be a regular search feed that then returns the content type - allowing me to filter by rss items only, or a special rss-only index.

Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Google AJAX Feed API. I was looking for feeds search for long, and evaluating Google's API now.